# Causal impact: how can i determine the incremental impact of campaign 1 when campaign 2 was so live in same markets and dates?

Tags: r, causalimpact

0

I have a theoretical / stats related question. I've run the package in R and it's easy. Question: How can I know the incremental impact of Campaign #1 during a period when Campaign #2 was also active during the same time period and in the same markets as Campaign #1?

r
statistics

Comment: Do you have any data for a period with only Campaign #1 or only Campaign #2, or do the two campaigns overlap entirely?

Comment: @BryanKrause completely overlap...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with any statistical model or software. You do not have two interventions, you have one intervention "Campaign 1+2". They are perfectly correlated and not possible to separate.

Your only hope would be if you could apply some prior domain-specific information to the problem. For example, if Campaign 1 said "buy oranges" and Campaign 2 said "buy apples", you could perhaps separate them by looking separately at apple and orange sales, rather than a composite "fruit sales", and using an assumption that a specific campaign for apples doesn't impact other fruits.